# How to add ending paren to a clojure form when using emacs with paredit?

Tags: emacs, clojure, paredit

I have the following form:

```
(defn common [title & body]
  (h/html5
  [:body
    [:div
  ]))
```

The problem is that I have a missing `]` at the end of the hiccup template and If I press `]` emacs does not add the missing `]` instead it just behaves like I pressed Ctrl+f. I know that this is because of paredit but I can't seem to find out how to add the missing `]` and this is starting to drive me crazy.

How can I add the missing paren when I'm using emacs with paredit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>C-q</kbd> (`quoted-insert`) before the bracket should work.